# Unlock a combo box when an option button is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to unlock a combobox when a option button is enabled. I am using the following code in a module but when I run the code and select the option the combo box remains locked

```
If Custom = True Then
  FromMonth.Locked = False
  FromYear.Locked = False
  ToMonth.Locked = False
  ToYear.Locked = False
End If
```

I am hoping to find a way to simultaneously click the option button in the userform and have it unlock the combo boxes next to them

Comment: How did you dimension `Custom`?  I believe you will you want `Custom.Value = True`, as well.

Comment: Perhaps `If Custom.Enabled Then`?

Comment: Is it an *ActiveX* combobox or a *Form Controls* combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option button change event, and make sure to add the code into userform code module and not the normal module

Your code can be something like this

```
Private Sub Custom_Change()
  FromMonth.Locked = Not Custom.Value
  FromYear.Locked = Not Custom.Value
  ToMonth.Locked = Not Custom.Value
  ToYear.Locked = Not Custom.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help you!